# How to validate email To header?

Tags: javascript, email-validation

I need to validate user input. The user can enter a full to header for an email message, so it may look like any of the following:

```
user@example.com
<user@example.com>
User <user@example.com>
"User" <user@example.com>
user@example.com, User2 <user2@example.com>
```

..etc. All of the above are valid To fields.

However, when user input is something like this:

```
user@example.com, not_an_email, User <user.example.com>
```

Then I want to respond with an error for the last 2 emails.

It's not a problem for me to check a plain email address for validity, but the extra String and braces <> I am a bit clueless about at the moment.

Comment: Did you try regex at all? Although its not a sure shot solution but it should take care for most of it.

Comment: I really do not know how to write regex at all...

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript